# How should I take the following sentence?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

In this context, how should I take the sentence 'Concourse alone is best'?

I don't catch its interpretation.

What does the word 'Concourse' mean?

Context:

> In that noble Toleration Edict, Asoka says: “Concourse alone is best,
> that is, all should listen willingly to the doctrine professed by
> others.”

Source: Buddhism in a Nutshell
P. 35 By Narada thera

Answer (score 4):

It means something like 'people coming together', but this is an unconventional use of the word.

By googling *toleration edict Asoka*, I found a better translation of what seems to be the passage in question;

> Therefore contact between religions is good. One should listen to and respect the doctrines professed by others.

(From [The Edicts of King Ashoka](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/%7Emalaiya/ashoka.html))

Comment: Thanks you so much for answering, Kate Bunting.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, "concourse" means the assembly or meeting of persons together. It is an uncommon usage that is becoming archaic in present-day English.

[Webster's 1828 Dictionary](https://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/concourse) has this as its second definition for "concourse":

> 2. A meeting; an assembly of men; an assemblage of things; a collection formed by a voluntary or spontaneous moving and meeting in
>    one place. Acts 19:40.

So to say "concourse alone is best" is to say people must meet and converse together.

Comment: Thanks you so much for answering, Biblasia.

Comment: @Biblasia:  How are you understanding **alone**?

Comment: @TimR In this context, "alone" means "only."